# Serving static content in a Tomcat webapp

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

In a Tomcat webapp in what circumstances should we
serve static content using Tomcat default servlet
and in what other case should we do it by placing it
in directories at the same level (not under, of course) of WEB-INF ?

I hope my question is clear enough,thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Files placed under WEB-INF are not accessible via URL so they cannot be served as static content. Typically you would place there all configuration files or other internals.

As for static content, you can use it for anything that does not need special access. For example if the content that can be seen depends on the user logged in, you would need to provide such a logic in your servlet and store the files under WEB-INF otherwise, anyone who can "guess" the correct URL would be able to retrieve them.